# Peak finding and analysis on python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I have written a code that reads in my data file and plots it and then fits it and finds the peaks however I have 6 peaks and the code is only currently fitting 2 of the peaks and isn't returning any data on them by code is as follows:

```
 from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from scipy.signal import find_peaks

 data = np.genfromtxt("C:\\Users\\lenovo laptop\\practice_data_ll16ame1.dat", skip_header = 15)
 x = data[: , 0]
 y = data[: , 1]

 plt.plot(x,y)
 plt.show()

 def func(x, *params):
   y = np.zeros_like(x)
   for i in range(0, len(params), 3):
    ctr = params[i]
    amp = params[i+1]
    wid = params[i+2]
    y = y + amp * np.exp( -((x - ctr)/wid)**2)
return y

guess = [0, 60000, 80, 1000, 60000, 80]
for i in range(12):
guess += [60+80*i, 46000, 25]   

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y, p0=guess)
fit = func(x, *popt)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x, fit , 'r-')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You have imported find_peaks which would identify the peaks you are looking for in an easier way than `func` . You can read about `scipy.signal.find_peaks` here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html

Comment: I am not sure how I would implement that into the code I have written the doc file is quite confusing.

Comment: Can you provide examples of your x and y data please?

Comment: Hello thank you so much for the reply, I have posted my data here: https://easyupload.io/zisc1v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I looked at the plot of your custom function, it was clear that the majority of points were in a more-or-less horizontal line, so the function wouldn't fit well to your peaks. Because there is no noise and the peaks are so prominent, you just need to pass the y values and a threshold to the `find_peaks` function.

By implementing find_peaks instead of your custom function, you get the following code:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

data = np.genfromtxt("C:\\Users\\lenovo laptop\\practice_data_ll16ame1.dat", skip_header = 15)
x = data[: , 0]
y = data[: , 1]

points = find_peaks(y, height = 100)

plt.plot(x, y)
for i in points[0]:
    plt.scatter(x[i], y[i])
plt.show()
```

Find_peaks returns a tuple consisting of two things:
1. The index of the peaks ( `points[0]` in the code above)
2. The height of each peak (`points[1]`)

The code yields the following plot, which I believe is what you want:[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, and if there was noise would I need to handle this differently

Comment: That would depend on the noise. If the noise reached as high as the lowest peak, then you would only get 5 peaks instead of 6. You could try smoothing the data using a mean filter to reduce noise but that could also obscure your peaks. Looking at the data will help you choose the best course of action